# How to add customer name to email in asp mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-email

I have a contact form and I want to pass the customer name to their email Ex, "Dear John Doe". How do I get the name to display?

I tried calling the @Model.Name and called the model class on the view and the email picked up the code instead of the value

My View

```
    @model MyProject.Models.ContactModel;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Thank You</title>
</head>
<body>
            <h1>Confirmation</h1>
            <p>
                Dear @Model.Name, <br /><br />
                Thank you for contacting us. This is  system generated response
            </p>
</body>
</html>
```

controller

```
 [HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(ContactModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        MailMessage CustomerMsg = new MailMessage();
        CustomerMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        CustomerMsg.From = new MailAddress("example.com support@example.com");
        CustomerMsg.To.Add(model.EmailContact);
        CustomerMsg.Subject = "Thank you for your submission";
        CustomerMsg.Body = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/Views/Contact/EmailTemplate.cshtml")))
        {
            CustomerMsg.Body = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
        {
            var credential = new NetworkCredential
            {
                UserName = "",
                Password = ""
            };

            smtp.Credentials = credential;
            smtp.Host = "mail.example.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.EnableSsl = false;
            try
            {
                await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
                await smtp.SendMailAsync(CustomerMsg);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Sent", "Home");
        }
    }
    return View(model);
```

model

```
public class ContactModel
{
    public string error { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = " Name field required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = " Email field required")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = " Valid email required")]
    public string EmailContact { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = " Feedback required")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You have to actually run the Razor engine against the cshtml. You can't just read it from a file and expect it to magically create HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I got it

I put {name} in my view and add this code to my controller and it worked perfectly

```
                   CustomerMsg.Body = string.Empty;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/Templates/Email.html")))
            {
                CustomerMsg.Body = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }


            CustomerMsg.Body = CustomerMsg.Body.Replace("{name}", model.Name.ToUpper());
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't see the "model" shown in your view.  Is it as simple as adding the model to the top of your view code? `@model Namespace.Models.ContactModel`  If all your passing is the name, then you could also just use "String" for your model `@model String` and then substitute `@Model` for `@Model.Name` below.

```
@model Namespace.Models.ContactModel
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Thank You</title>
</head>
<body>
            <h1>Confirmation</h1>
            <p>
                Dear @Model.Name, <br /><br />
                Thank you for contacting us. This is  system generated response
            </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes I have that, it didn't work for some reason the email reads out all the code

Comment: Did you look at how he's getting the body of the email? Simply reading the cshtml from the disk. That's not going to work.